# Following a tutorial for web services, hit a wall, cannot figure out what to do

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I am following this tut:
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/1d42da/a-xml-web-service-that-update-data-into-a-default-table-of-t/

And I got to step 10:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int sn = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text);
    int batch = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox2.Text);
    string year = TextBox3.Text;
    localhost.Service myservice = new localhost.Service();
    int temp= myservice.Getupdate(sn,batch,year);
    if (temp== 1)
        {
           Label1.Text = "record is update";
        }
    else
       {
           Label1.Text = "record is not update";
       }
}
```

I am getting an error from `Getupdate`, the error being

`'CollegeSystemWebsite.SampleService' does not contain a definition for 'Getupdate' and no extension method 'Getupdate' accepting a first argument of type 'CollegeSystemWebsite.SampleService' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

I'm not sure if the tut is missing something or I just cant figure out what is wrong here.

Comment: can you show us your GetUpdate method, please ? checl is a WebMethod

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the signature is it good ?

```
 [WebMethod]
 public int Getupdate(int sn, int batch, string year)
 {
     /***/
 }
```

Comment: Sorry, with your comment above, you told me the error, I forgot to rename Getupdate to what I had changed my web method. Thank you